# How to do Case Insensitive Search on ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search data from Elastic Search Index with Case Insensitivity. For a example the word "Cat" can be search from "cat" ,"caT" ,"CAT" etc..

Please guide me to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field is `analyzed`, you can use [match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

```
{
"match" : {
    "message" : "cat"
    }
 }
```

Comment: I am almost new to elasticsearch. Please tell me how to analyzed the field.

Thank You

Comment: By default all Strings are `analyzed`. You can check the mapping of index using `GET /index-name/type-name/_mapping`

Comment: Using the _mapping API how can I tell if a field is analyzed?